# pgfplot plot difference in x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, resolution

I have a bunch of data where the x-axis is in seconds. I want to plot a snippet of this data, which means the starting point is going to be a pretty high number:

**example of snippet test.csv:**

```
X   Y
28600.13103 11
28602.81423 17
28605.80943 23
28606.85463 25
28607.89983 27
28608.75783 49
28609.77183 51
28610.80143 33
28612.09623 10
28614.73263 41
28617.08823 45
28618.38303 48
28619.84943 50
```

So if this is plottet with following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{height=6cm,width=10cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled y ticks=false,
        enlarge x limits=false]
        \addplot +[mark=none] table[col sep=tab,x expr=\thisrowno{0},y={Y}] {test.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The x-axis resolution becomes really bad:

[image]

And I don't have room for non shortened values.

So is there a way to plot only the difference in seconds and then having a node in each end telling which hour its in?

Comment: I guess you already know this, but maybe it can be useful. A manual (i.e. not automatic) solution could be to use `x expr=\thisrowno{0}-28600.13103`, where the number is taken from the first data row.

Comment: thank's @LucaD I actually didn't think about that. This would do the trick, but an automatic method would be preferred

Answer (score 4):

Is this automatic enough? I don't know exactly what kind of output you had in mind.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{height=6cm,width=10cm,compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X   Y
28600.13103 11
28602.81423 17
28605.80943 23
28606.85463 25
28607.89983 27
28608.75783 49
28609.77183 51
28610.80143 33
28612.09623 10
28614.73263 41
28617.08823 45
28618.38303 48
28619.84943 50
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\mydata

\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{X}\of{\mydata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\startsec}{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        clip mode=individual,
        scaled y ticks=false,
        enlarge x limits=false]
        \addplot +[mark=none] table[x expr={\thisrowno{0}-\startsec},y=Y] {\mydata};
        \node [below=0.6cm,anchor=east] at (rel axis cs:1,0) {$+\startsec\,\mathrm{s}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Torbjørn T. I don't have anything specific in mind, but it contains some methods that I defenetly will use in my application.